# How do I use Marshal.QueryInterface?

Tags: c#

I am trying to work with some embedded objects in Word documents. An earlier poster told me that this is not straight forward. Here is an excerpt of the linked answer:

> "As I mentioned earlier, utilizing the
>   embedded object's programming model to
>   perform the save is something of a
>   shortcut.  There is a more involved
>   solution that will work with any
>   embedded object.  In order for the
>   object to be embedded in the first
>   place, it must support one of the COM
>   IPersist interfaces (i.e
>   IPersistStorage, IPersistStreamInit,
>   IPersistFile, etc).  Therefore, an
>   embedded object can always be
>   extracted by calling
>   Marshal.QueryInterface on the
>   OLEFormat.Object (to determine the
>   appropriate persistance interface),
>   casting accordingly and then calling
>   the appropriate method.  Depending on
>   which persistence interface you use,
>   you may need to call some additional
>   methods to expose the appropriate
>   storage over the top of a file.  Also,
>   depending on the type of embedded
>   object, you may still need to activate
>   the object prior to being able to
>   successfully QueryInterface for the
>   persistance interfaces."

So I am interested in exposing which interface the object is implementing. The closest I could find is [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop/2007-07/msg00054.html). The code so far is below and any help with the Marshal.QueryInterface is greatly appreciated.

```
// Opening the word document
object missing = Type.Missing;
this.document = wordApp.Documents.Open(
                ref fn, ref confirmConversions, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape inlineShape in this.document.InlineShapes)
            {
                if (inlineShape.OLEFormat.ProgID != null)
                {
                    switch (inlineShape.OLEFormat.ProgID)
                    {
                        // This is a pdf file
                        case "AcroExch.Document.7":
                            //Marshal.QueryInterface(IntPtr pUnk, ref Guid iid, out IntPtr ppv);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Marshal.QueryInterface` shouldn't be necessary - if you take a COM object and cast it to a COM interface type, .NET does the `QueryInterface` call for you. That is, you can write: `IPersistStorage persist = (IPersistStorage) obj;`

However it's not clear to me which object in the code implements `IPersistStorage`, `IPersistStreamInit` etc.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'IPersistStorage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I have cast to an interface before, but I read that this can be done if the object implements the interface. But how do I add the reference/assembly? I can't seem to find its origin. Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: @Kasper I don't know of a ready-made declaration of `IPersistStorage` in .NET, but you can declare it in your own code. COM objects 'magically' implement a given interface as long as you give that interface the correct `[Guid]`. Here's an example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/bc85ed23-2273-4b33-b862-354b61294968/

Comment: Thank you. But I get "InvalidCastException - Specified cast is not valid.", so I guess that the object doesn't implement the IPersistStorage interface, but rather IPersistStreamInit, IPersistFile or some other.

Comment: @Kasper That sounds plausible. You can use `IPersistStorage maybePersist = obj as IPersistStorage` to check.

Comment: @Kasper I'm still not clear on where the COM object is here. Do you have to instantiate it from scratch, given the ProgID?

Comment: The IPersistStorage maybePersist = obj as IPersistStorage doesn't work either. I simply think the object doesn't implement that interface. As mentioned earlier, I was interested in calling Marshal.QueryInterface on the OLEFormat.Object to determine the appropriate persistence interface. Then I can cast accordingly and call the appropriate save method.

Comment: IPersistStorage persist = (IPersistStorage)inlineShape.OLEFormat.Object as IPersistStorage; //COM object?

Comment: `IPersistStorage persist = inlineShape.OLEFormat.Object as IPersistStorage; if (persist == null) { /* try a different interface */ } else { hooray! }`

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what you intend to do but calling `QueryInterface` can be done. The only problem is that you have a `ProgID` here and you need to get the `CLSID` from it first. You can do by pInvoking the CLSIDFromProgId function.

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
static extern int CLSIDFromProgID([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszProgID, out Guid pclsid);
```

And then, you can call this as follows:

```
Marshal.QueryInterface(IntPtr.Zero, CLSIDFromProgID(progID), out pInterface);
```

Comment: How do I call it? The CLSIDFromProgID has 2 parameters and you use only 1.